# Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded android studio and created a fresh project. I didn't have problems at first. I added some action bar buttons then came back to my package to see this error. I double checked my xml files if there was anything wrong. It also says "cannot resolve method 'add' and 'commit'". But all these methods takes android.R stuff as parameters. I am using an action bar support for android 2.1 devices. It seems I will never get rid of these android.R problems, not even in android studio. So what could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Edit : Why the downvote? I found lots of google results related to this issue but they were all about  either eclipse or android.R and android.R solutions such as importing your app's R class didn't help and as I stated it's a fresh main activity that supports v7 action bar with optimized imports.
Here's the code anyway :

```
package com.example.training;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: It's a fresh main activity.

Comment: Post your specific error message and your build.gradle

Comment: It seems that your project can't compile, and R. doesn't exists.
Try to clean your project (with gradlew clean) and check the problems section (you can find it in the combo on the top on the left).

Comment: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Training:processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':Training:processDebugResources'

Here's the error message I get when I try to clean the project.

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: build.gradle is empty.

Answer (score 7):

First, you're using the wrong `R`:

```
setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_main);
```

Remove the `android.` -- it should be the `R` class generated for your app package. (Ditto for the few other places where you're referencing `android.R`.)

For the `add()` and `commit()` errors: they are from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` but since you're not referencing `FragmentTransaction` by the class name, you don't need the import. Possibly the `android-support-v4.jar` is missing from project.

Overall, Android Studio is still an early access preview and will have rough edges all around. For beginners, Eclipse/ADT will offer a much smoother learning path.

Comment: I can't remove android. It goes back to 'android.R...' automatically. About importing android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction, it turns grey which I believe means unused or unnecessary.

Comment: I wasted 3 hours on this. I suppose I'll switch back to Eclipse. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @Nik things are more worst in eclipse. Do clean and rebuild your project and then try to remove the android from R file import. If you still have problem make sure you have your R file in project created properly check YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_MODULE/build/source/r/....yourpackage_dir_structure..

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Android studio (on the odd occasion for some reason) fail to add the application R file correctly.

Try adding:

```
import <packagename>.app.R;
```

to the top of your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the path to the project there is no foldername having whitespace.
While creating a project the specified path folders must not contain any space in their naming

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in your res directory files: the resource compiler cannot run if there is no R.java class in the gen directory. Take a look at your res files: a common error could be a android:id duplicate name element in a xml layout, if you modified it (copy/paste of element without renaming the id).

Answer (score 0):

Got this working on Android Studio, following the example code on adding fragments.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Rather than using .add() directly on:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
```

Try explicitly creating fragmentTransaction and adding to it on a separate line.
Also had to specify android.app.FragmentTransaction to avoid support.v4, like so:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Good luck.